# Indenting specific environment deeper in AUCTeX

Tags: indentation, auctex

Is it possible to encourage AUCTeX to indent specific environment contents deeper than other environments? My specific case is getting the following indentation for chorus:

```latex
\begin{song}
\begin{verse}
  Normal 2-spaces indentation
\end{verse}
\begin{chorus}
      Would be great to have it indented
      deeper.
\end{chorus}
\end{song}
```

I tried playing with `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`. It works well to avoid indenation where inappropriate, the following

```lisp
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("song"  (lambda() 0)))
```

nicely disabled indentation inside `song`, but similar trick:.

```lisp
 (add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list
     '("chorus"  (lambda() (* 3 LaTeX-indent-level))))
```

ends up closing such environment incorrectly:

```latex
\begin{verse}
  Normal 2-spaces indentation
\end{verse}
\begin{chorus}
      Would be great to have it indented
      deeper.
      \end{chorus}
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function listed in `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` should also cater for backindenting the `\end`, see for example `LaTeX-indent-tabular`.  Add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(defun mg-LaTeX-indent-chorus ()
  (cl-destructuring-bind
   (beg-pos . beg-col)
   (LaTeX-env-beginning-pos-col)
   (cond ((looking-at "\\\\end{chorus}")
      beg-col)

     (t
      (+ (* 3 LaTeX-indent-level) beg-col)))))

(defun mg-LaTeX-indent-song ()
  (save-excursion
    (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
    (current-column)))

(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("song"   mg-LaTeX-indent-song))
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("chorus" mg-LaTeX-indent-chorus))
```

Now the following LaTeX code is correctly indented:

```latex
\begin{foo}
  \begin{song}
  \begin{verse}
    Normal 2-spaces indentation
  \end{verse}
  \begin{chorus}
        Would be great to have it indented
        deeper.
  \end{chorus}
  \end{song}
\end{foo}
```

Comment: Is there any way to indent every begin...end like for...else inside a function in C/C++ source code?