# How can I prevent auctex to indent a new environment inside another environment?

Tags: auctex

Suppose I enter the following code using `LaTeX-environment`

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pycode}
        a = 2
    \end{pycode}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then auctex automatically indents as shown above. This is not desired since it will bring error messages if I compile it via pythontex because of wrong indentation.

So I have two question:

1. How to prevent that the `pycode` environment becomes indented if it is insied any other environment (for example tikzpicture)
2. How to prevent that code inside a `pycode` environment is indented by auctex.

Note that this is a follow up question to [Pythontex and auctex](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20136/2323), so the solution should work together with `mmm-mode`.

**Edit**

After giordanos suggestion I made a minimal .emacs file:

```
(require 'package)
;; (add-to-list 'package-archives 
;;     '("marmalade" .
;;       "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
;; (add-to-list 'package-archives
;;              '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

;; (setq package-archive-enable-alist '(("melpa" deft magit)))


(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auctex")

(package-initialize)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()

(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "pycode")
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list
        '("pycode" current-indentation))
))


(require 'python)
(defun python-indent-guess-indent-offset ()
  "Guess and set `python-indent-offset' for the current buffer."
  (interactive))

(require 'mmm-auto)
(mmm-add-group 'latex-python
 '((latex-python-envs
    :submode python-mode
    :face mmm-default-submode-face
    :front "\\\\begin{\\(pycode\\|pyverbatim\\)}\n"
    :back "\\\\end{~1}\n"
    :save-matches 1)

   (latex-python-cmds
    :submode python-mode
    :face mmm-default-submode-face
    :front "\\\\pyc?{"
    :back "}")))

;; (setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)
;; (setq mmm-submode-decoration-level 0)
(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'latex-mode nil 'latex-python)
;; (global-set-key [(f11)] 'mmm-parse-buffer)

(advice-add 'LaTeX-insert-environment ':after '(lambda (env) (mmm-parse-block 2)))
```

It works but messes up the syntax highlighting:

[image: output 1]

If I do `C-c C-n`, it becomes ok, but the mmm-mode get's disabled:

[image: output 2]

If I enable the mmm-mode again, I get the first picture again.

Answer (score 6):

Add to your init file

```lisp
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "pycode")
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list
        '("pycode" current-indentation))
```

See [`(info "(auctex)Verbatim content")`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Verbatim-content) and [`(info "(auctex)Indenting")`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Indenting).

Comment: Thanks, that solves problem 2. For the first problem, the `\begin{pycode}` remains indented. Any idea?

Comment: See the updated answer, you should add `pycode` also to `LaTeX-verbatim-environments`.

Comment: This solves the indentation problem, but messes up the syntax highlighting, here is a screenshot: https://www.anony.ws/image/J4fd

Comment: Uh, doesn't happen for me.  Try to revert the buffer with `C-c C-n`.

Comment: Doesn't help. I will try it with a fresh .emacs file and report my results.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: My answer explains what one should do on AUCTeX side, I'm not familiar with `mmm`, it seems it's that package that messes font-locking up