# Polymode with python and latex-mode

Tags: polymode

The [polymode](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode) manual suggests that creating new polymodes should be very easy:

> Creating new polymodes typically takes a few lines of code.

I wanted to set it up to make emacs to switch to python mode inside of `pythontex` commands and environments. For the object oriented approach seems to be more complex to modify than just adding some delimiters to a list in my .emacs file. So I don't even see how to start and where to save apply my modifications.

So how would the equivalent setup for polymode look like as that given by JeanPierre for mmm-mode: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20150/2323

Comment: Note that the package author is in the midst (as of February 2016) of a complete rewrite of polymode. It may be a little unstable until this transition is complete. It sounds like that may be finished shortly, but beware (and patient) in the meantime.

Answer (score 6):

Following the example at https://github.com/vspinu/polymode/tree/master/modes:

```
  (require 'polymode)

  (defcustom pm-inner/python
    (pm-hbtchunkmode "python"
                     :mode 'python-mode
                     :head-reg  "\\\\begin{pycode}"
                     :tail-reg  "\\\\end{pycode}")
    "python typical chunk."
    :group 'innermodes
    :type 'object)

  (defcustom pm-poly/latex-python
    (pm-polymode-one "latex-python"
                     :hostmode 'pm-host/latex
                     :innermode 'pm-inner/python)
    "latex-python typical polymode."
    :group 'polymodes
    :type 'object)

  (define-polymode poly-latex+python-mode pm-poly/latex-python)
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tex$" . poly-latex+python-mode))
```

It appears to work, though I only tested it briefly. This snippet can go in your `.emacs`, `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or wherever you put your personal emacs configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works, but with some problems: Syntax highlighting seems to be unreliable, Indenting doesn't work as well (TAB works only for two levels). Since polymode uses indirect buffers, everything inside the pycode environment should work just as in a python buffer.

Comment: It mostly works as expected for me. Syntax highlighting is as it is in a `.py` buffer, indenting with tab works correctly. I have emacs 24.5.1, python 3.5.1.