# Is there a way to have multiple modes in one buffer?

Tags: multiple-modes

This is kind of a weird question, but I have a file that's a mix of perl, text, and Bourne shell.  Is there some (easy) way to have emacs switch major modes at different points in the file?

Perhaps when it sees `-*- Text -*-` or `-*- Perl -*-` or something?

Or can I just change it for the region if I `narrow-to-region`?

Thanks.

-E

I just noticed that there is a tag for "multiple-modes", so I'm hopeful.

Comment: Please have a look at a google search for “emacs multiple modes” and try out the options that pop up.

Comment: You find [a reference of `mmm-mode`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20136/pythontex-and-auctex) with a configuration example [in that answer to another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20150/2370). From my point of view this question is actually a [duplicate of that other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20136/2370).

Comment: @Tobias: Agreed - voted to close as dup. It would be good if Someone (TM) edited that question to present the question more generally and to have a title like this one.

Comment: @Drew [Better?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20136/2370) I admit I was not very original with the new name;-).

Comment: @Tobias: Definitely. Thx.

Comment: @Tobias  So, I did search before hand and didn't see the one mentioned.  Should I change the title?  To what?  In any case, thanks.  I'll look around. -E

Comment: @ErikBennett Hi Erik, if [the linked post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20150/2370) answers your question everything is fine and you did great in improving the site with your question. The title of the other question has been generalized so that a search for `multiple modes in one buffer` gives that answer as one of the first results. It should be relatively simple to adapt the [linked solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20150/2370) to your problem. Side note: I found the other post by a tag search with search string `[multiple-modes]`.

Comment: @Tobias  The linked post should answer the question.  The problem now is that I haven't written any lisp code since the 80s for emacs 18.  For example, I don't know what `:save-matches` does.  It's a different question for a different post.  This is enough for me to chew on for a while.  Thanks!  -E

Comment: You get an info documentation shipped with mmm-mode. See `M-: (info "(mmm) Paired Delimiters")` for a description of `:save-matches`.