# mmm-mode strange behavior with perl-shell-script

Tags: bash, perl, mmm-mode

Background: I've been working with a program that is about half Bash
and half perl.  I thought I'd give mmm-mode a try since it sounded
like just the mode for me.  I don't know lisp well enough to be
useful.

I used "elpa" to install mmm-mode.  It didn't install the
documentation anyplace my emacs could find it.  There was no
`mmm.info` file anywhere on the system (though there was a texinfo file).  So I downloaded the
`mmm-mode-master.zip` and installed it.  So far, so good.

I added the following to my `~/.emacs` file.

```
(require 'mmm-auto)

(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)

(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'perl-mode nil 'perl-shell-script)

(mmm-add-group 'perl-shell-script
 '((perl-shell-script-here
    :submode shell-script-mode
    :face mmm-default-submode-face
    :front "#begin-shell-script-mode\n"
    :back "#end-shell-script-mode\n"
    :save-matches 1)))
```

I based this on this post: [Multiple major modes in one buffer (e.g., python-mode & LaTeX-mode)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20136/multiple-major-modes-in-one-buffer-e-g-python-mode-latex-mode/20150#20150) I think the `:save-matches` is unused in my case, but it shouldn't be an error.

**The problem**: The `<tab>` key doesn't work within the "shell-script"
portion of the file.

I "believe" that mmm-mode is working correctly.  The highlighting
changes.  The mode line changes.  It *seems* to contain the correct
information: `(Perl[Shell-script] MMM)`.

I checked the  key binding (C-h k): `TAB (translated from <tab>) runs the command indent-for-tab-command`.

But all it really does is insert a '\t'.

I can't tell if the trouble is `mmm-mode`, `shell-script-mode`, or
`perl-mode` (I'm not using `cperl-mode` at this point).

Any ideas?

-E

Sample file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>) {
    print;
}
printf(<<"BASHSHELL",
#begin-shell-script-mode

while getopts "ca" options; do
    case "\${options}" in
    c ) 
        echo "Cleaning up."
        cleanup  
        exit 0
        ;;
    a )
        echo "Setting auto clean up for %s."
        AUTOCLEANUP=1
        ;;
    * )
        echo "Usage: \$0 [-c]"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
#end-shell-script-mode
BASHSHELL
       "FOO");
```