# Mode to edit SQL code inside XML tags

Tags: sql, xml

I'm new to emacs, does anybody know is there a way to combine xml-mode and sql-mode so SQL code inside tags can be highlighted and proper indent?

example

```
<FnTable ID="MyCode">

  declare @ID bigint = @p0

  select * from Company.Table where ID = @ID 

</FnTable>
```

Comment: Sorry @tobias i was too late to reply, got it working using mmm-mode and doing some tests, my closed issued here for reference: https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/issues/91 Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question qualifies as duplicate of [that question about "Multiple major modes in one buffer"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20136/2370).
Therefore it should be closed.

Nevertheless, since you are new to Emacs I give you below a modified version of the code block from [the accepted answer of the duplicate](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20150/2370) that should solve your problem.
Copy that code block into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), which is most often one of `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

If you use that code block make sure that you have installed `mmm-mode`.
You can check or run the installation of `mmm-mode` with the menu item `Options->Manage Emacs Packages`.
See the [manual page about Emacs packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html) for other ways of managing packages.

```el
(require 'mmm-auto)
(mmm-add-classes
 '((nxml-sql
    :submode sql-mode
    :face mmm-default-submode-face
    :front "<FnTable\\( ID=\".*\"\\)?>\n"
    :back "</FnTable>\n")))

(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)
(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'nxml-mode nil 'nxml-sql)
```